# In SharePoint 2013, how to embed one site page into another?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, reusable-content

I have some common content as Site Pages, lets call it "Page 1", which I want to show in "Page 2" and "Page 3", just as it is shown in Page 1, so that I can just update Page 1, and Page 2 and Page 3 will start showing the updated content. All pages have simple HTML Content.

I can see it has to do something with Web Parts. But for the love of my life, i am not able to achieve this.

Please note that I am using enterprise SharePoint 2013, so if there is a setting that can block me for achieving the above, please let me know, so that I can get it corrected.

Comment: Related question on Sharepoint Online "modern": https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/310564/how-to-include-content-of-one-page-in-another-page-in-sharepoint-online-modern

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, you want to place the same HTML content on multiple pages.  It sounds like you are half-way there when you mentioned a Content Editor.  Quite simply, you can save your HTML file wherever you’d like in your SharePoint site (like in a document library, perhaps).  Then copy the URL to that HTML file to your clipboard.  Edit a SharePoint page (i.e., page 2, page 3, etc.) and add a web part -> content editor.  Finally, all you have to do is edit the content editor by clicking the down arrow at the top right corner of the content editor.  At the top right of your screen you can paste in the link to your HTML file in the section called “Content Link”, then click Ok/Apply and stop editing the page.

You can repeat this process on other pages...or, pro-tip - in the edit page mode, you can click the arrow at the top right of the content editor web part and click “Export.”  This allows you to save the web part (with the link to your HTML content).  On other pages, when your are ready to add the content editor, instead you can upload the web part, then add to your page.

Hope this helps!  We use this to embed HTML across about 100 SharePoint pages, and we can simply update the one HTML file to update all of the pages.

Edit: Depending on how you want to implement this, Ganesh’s post below is helpful, too.  You could use a Page Viewer web part instead of a content editor if you would like to place the external HTML page within an iframe.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thank You for the reply.

Comment: I tried doing the steps, but the content editor is not showing any thing. A little more information: The HTML File I have uploaded, I used an existing Site Page (Page 1) and used Edit Source and wrapped it around with <html> </html>. Uploaded this HTML file in the Site Assets. Then I added the content editor in Page 2 and in the Content Link, add the path for the html.

Comment: Hmm, so are you saying you took the source HTML from "Page 1.aspx" and just added <html> and </html> tags to it?  If so, I do not think that would work since SharePoint aspx pages are built/wrapped with various objects to create all of the ribbons, headers, etc.  Even if it did work, you would see all of the banners and headers twice (one inside of the other).  Can you post your HTML file to this thread?

Comment: The HTML opened fine in a browser (just has a 2 tables with 3/4 rows each). Cannot paste the entire code due to text limit -

Comment: <html>
<table width="100%" class="ms-rteTable-default" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default">Lorem</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit &#160;voluptate velit esse cillum.</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default">Ipsum</td>
         <td class="ms-rteTable-default">
            <p>voluptate velit esse cillum.</p>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</html>

Comment: Ok, I think I might understand your problem based on your comments below (indicating that all of the extra navigation and toolbars are reappearing when you put the page in iframes).  It sounds like you just took the source code from "Page 1" and slapped <html> tags around it.  When adding the page via content editor, SharePoint will fail to render the html because you have reintroduced all of the SharePoint objects (navigation menus, ribbons, etc.).  Instead, your "Page 1" HTML file should only have the minimal tags needed to make your table.

Comment: In other words, the code you pasted above, just paste that in a new text file, then change the file extension to .html and upload it to your document library.  Next, try adding that URL location via content editor on "Page 2".  The table should appear properly (did for me, at least) without any extra content.

Comment: The HTML in question is a basic one, with one simple table. It does not have any frills that comes with an ASPX file. Let's see if this clarifies the issue - C1.HTML and C2.aspx, both these 2 files have the same table. I have uploaded both in Site Assets Folder. Now, if I open C1.HTML in a browser directly, it shows the table, but If I click on the same in SP, it downloads the html file instead of showing in the Browser (May be some enterprise setting caused this). For the ASPX file, if I add it in an iframe, it shows all the top and left ribbons, which I am suppressing using a Javascript code

Comment: Ahh, the JavaScript code might be your culprit.  I used script to hide my left and top navigation menus once, in addition to a content editor calling an HTML file, and the HTML didn’t show up until I rearranged the order of the web parts.  Have you tried swapping your script and HTML file, by chance?

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding the simple content using HTML and content editor webpart, I will suggest you the below approach:

1. Write all your code in single HTML file.
2. Save it in site assets/style library.
3. Add content editor webpart on all 3 pages.
4. Reference the HTML file from site assets/style library (like given in below image).
5. Whenever you will make any changes in HTML file and re-upload in site assets/style library, all 3 pages will be updated and show same content.

[image]

**References**:

1. [Content Editor Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/content-editor-web-part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc)

Comment: I uploaded the HTML, which opens fine in the browser. But when I put the path in the Content Link, it did not show anything. The Content Editor showed blank.

Comment: Are you saying that it is working on page 1 and not working on page 2?or is it not working on either of the pages?

Comment: I think there is a little confusion. "Page1.html" is a simple html in my Site Contents folder. Which I have put in "Page2.aspx" as Content Editor in the Content Link field - As shown above in your reply. When I click Apply or Okay, or even save Page2.aspx, the Content Editor frame shows blank. Am I doing something wrong in saving the Page1.html file in Site Contents, when I click on the Page1.html file in Site Contents folder, it downloads the file instead of displaying the content.

Comment: I think you are doing it right. Just check the path your providing to your HTML file is correct. Also, after adding the webpart and saving the page, check if there is any error in browser console.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, you can use page viewer webpart.

What is Page viewer web part in SharePoint?

The page viewer web part is used to display the webpage, file or the folder inside a WebPage. Once we place the Page Viewer web Part in a site Page, it automatically inserts the HTML IFrame Element.

How to add the page viewer web part?

To insert the Page Viewer Web part , we need to follow the below steps.

1. Click on the Edit Page on a Site Page Where you want to insert the page viewer Web Part
2. Select Page Viewer from Media and Content  of Categories Section

Answer (score 0):

You could insert embed code in the page2

[image]

And type the embed code as below:

```
<iframe src="http://spsite/pages/page1.aspx" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi, This seems to be working. But the only issue is that the aspx page is coming with a bunch of extra navigation and tool bars, the same way the link opens. Is there a way to suppress everything else but content? I would be grateful, if you can share the process of eliminating these extra parts (which are common for all Site Pages), when I embed it in different pages.

Comment: Update: I found a way to suppress them using Java script. But it is very cumbersome. If nothing else works, I will go that way. Cannot believe it is so difficult, when it should have been a straight forward configuration in SP to show comment content from other Site Pages.